# Как telegram Api в разных чатах устанавливает айди сообщениям? я думал что с 0 или с 1, но судя по моим тестам - нет, не понимаю

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

Всем доброго времени суток, написал я простенького бота для телеграм на пхп, мини доска обьявлений, и некоторый функционал завязан на айди смс в чатах, для отслеживания этих самых смс создал 3 базы, т.к есть канал куда сообщения отправляет бот, админский чат, и куча личных чатов через которые юзеры и добавляют контент...

Но вот незадача при первом же релизе все посыпалось, потому что **по моей логике телеграм в каждом новом приватном чате должен был начинать с 0 или с 1 вести айди смс, но как я понял он каждый раз продолжает нумерацию, прав ли я, и как быть в таком случае с группами, и каналами, там тоже продолжается нумерация или нет, или может я не прав?**

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно. Храните в БД ID чата, который должен быть уникальным, и ID сообщения, который может повторяться. Когда Вам нужно сообщение, запрашивайте сообщение с этим ID, которое принадлежит к конкретному чату.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я тоже думал, что логика такая, но почему телеграм бот отправляет в личном чате в котором от силы 100 сообщений свое смс с айди 10 654 например, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Хм, как мне кажется, с ботом общаются и другие люди, и ID обновляется. Если вы посмотрите, в новом боте, то сообщения там будут начинаться с 1

Comment: Вот я и пытаюсь понять как в каждом новом чате идет нумерация айди, и не понимаю, сообщения от юзера с нуля а от бота продолжается счет из других чатов?

Comment: Логика довольно простая, в чате пишут сообщение и другие пользователи, соответственно счётчик меняется. Для нового чата он так же начинается с 1. Точно так же и личкой в боте, люди пишут боту, но не Вы один это делаете.

Comment: Про чат я понимаю, если много людей, а если это приватный чат, т.е я один ему пишу в данном чате, у нашего чата есть свой айди, и в этом чате у бота айди записывается как будто после какого-то другого, я тестировал у людей кто не вел переписок с ботом, и все равно айди в приватном чате у сообщения бота имело очень большую цифру, я вот про что

Answer (score 0):

Спустя пару дней ожидания точного ответа, я решил все проверять собственными силами, и к чему я пришел.

**У телеграмма есть 3 варианта диалога**

1. приватный это все личные чаты с пользователями
2. Групповой, это все сообщения которые идут в группе
3. Канальный, для каналов.

**В чем же сама соль? Сколько бы ни было личных диалогов, вся нумерация айди в них строится последовательно, т.е пример:
Диалог 1 имеет 5 сообщений , где айди например 3,4,5,6,7 и вот боту пишут в диалог 2, тоже 5 сообщений, и айди смс 2го диалога станет 8,9,10,11,12 если же дальше будут сообщения в 1м диалоге, то счет продолжится с 12.**

Для каналов и групп я не проверял вариант, но думаю считается +- так же